# How can i execute DLL in custom action in installshield basic msi project?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I have created a class library project in C#, and I want to execute the output dll of that project in custom action of my Basic MSI project.

Comment: I found the way to create the New Standard DLL custom action,
but still it gives me error like "Cannot find entry point of function 'my function name', make sure it is exported."

anyone please suggest solution for this...!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Everyone,

I certainly found the solution, Actually the mistake was doing was, i was taking New Standard DLL custom action for executing C# DLL, but i choose Managed Code Custom action and i can execute my DLL without any problem...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# you can try creating an installer class action. Here is a tutorial which may help you:
http://devcity.net/Articles/339/1/article.aspx

If you want to use a standard Windows Installer action, you will need a win32 DLL:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

Comment: Thanks Cosmin,
but please can you help me with the error that i am facing as mentioned in above comment..?

i have defined execution sequence to the "After Installation Finalized", but my doubt is, the DLL is not loaded at this point of installation....

Comment: The error suggests that your DLL is not supported as a custom action. Try creating an installer class or win32 DLL.

Comment: So you mean to say is, DLL created in C# is not supported in Installshield Custom Action...??

Comment: Yes, you can't use any DLL as a custom action. It can be an installer, class, a standard DLL (usually C++) or a win32 DLL.

Comment: ohh....
can you suggest me any other way for this..??
i mean how can i create standard DLL or what is MSI DLL or how can i use MSI DLL..!!

Comment: My post includes two suggestions which are supported by MSI packages. You can either create an installer class action or a win32 DLL. These are the options for a DLL custom action.

Comment: Ok... i have added installer class to my DLL, now what i should do...??

Comment: Select the DLL component and set ".NET Installer Class" attribute to "Yes": http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpCompProperties.htm  http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IDlgNETInstClsArgs.htm